# Flutter GraphQL FormatException, FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1

Tags: flutter, graphql

I am following the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-simple-application-with-flutter-and-graphql-5786764df102) to use [flutter-graphql](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter) in my project. I have my api build with Laravel [graphql-laravel](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel). I want to get all users from api to display in my flutter project, and facing problem `FormatException, FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1`. the data response from my api and the tutorial I am following is the same.  the following is my code:

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
...

GraphQLConfiguration graphQLConfiguration = GraphQLConfiguration();

void main() => runApp(
  GraphQLProvider(
    client: graphQLConfiguration.client,
    child: CacheProvider(child: MyApp()),
  ),
);

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void getUsers() async {
    QueryMutation queryMutation = QueryMutation();
    GraphQLClient _client = graphQLConfiguration.clientToQuery();
    QueryResult result = await _client.query(
      QueryOptions(
        document: queryMutation.getUsers(),
      ),
    );
    print(result);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUsers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'GraphQL',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
        home:body: Text('Hello'),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

**GraphQLConf.dart**

```
    import "package:flutter/material.dart";
    import "package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart";

    class GraphQLConfiguration {
      static HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
        uri: "http://127.0.0.1/julin/api",
        headers: {
          'accept':'*/*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          'Charset': 'utf-8'
        }
      );

      ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
        GraphQLClient(
          link: httpLink,
          cache: OptimisticCache(dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject),
        ),
      );

      GraphQLClient clientToQuery() {
        return GraphQLClient(
          cache: OptimisticCache(dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject),
          link: httpLink,
        );
      }
    }
```

**QueryMutation.dart**

```
class QueryMutation {

  String getUsers() {
    return """
     {
       users {
          id
          name
          email
        }
      }
    """;
  }

}
```

I trying to solve this problem by following the answers from Stackoverflow and google all day, but right now really get stuck have no idea to solve this. please every one with experience with flutter GraphQL and graphql Laravel help me. 
Thanks u a lot.